# Remove content from /var/lib/yum/plugins/local in Centos

Tags: linux, centos, yum, rpm

The */var/lib/yum/plugins/local* folder seems to store installed rpm packages:

```
$ ls /var/lib/yum/plugins/local
389-ds-base-1.2.11.15-95.el6_9.x86_64.rpm
389-ds-base-devel-1.2.11.15-95.el6_9.i686.rpm 
...
yum-plugin-versionlock-1.1.30-42.el6_10.noarch.rpm
yum-updateonboot-1.1.30-42.el6_10.noarch.rpm
yum-utils-1.1.30-42.el6_10.noarch.rpm
```

At the same time, the directory has a pretty huge size: 2.9Gb.

The question is if it is safe to remove some RPM from there?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Or you can disable it. Read about the plugin here: https://fedoramagazine.org/use-the-dnf-local-plugin-to-speed-up-your-home-lab/